# Connecting ASP.NET client-side scripts to instances

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Consider this simplified example:

Server side ASP.NET-code:

```
TextBox theTextBox = ...
theTextBox.Attributes.Add("onchange", "HandleOnChangeEvent");
```

Client-side javascript:

```
var numberOfChanges;

function HandleOnChangeEvent() {
   numberOfChanges++;
   alert(numberOfChanges);
}
```

Now, this works, i.e. each time the user changes the value in the textbox, a dialog will popup showing the number of times the value in the textbox has changed since the page was loaded.

But what if there are multiple instances of the texbox on the same page? The numberOfChanges is global, thus it will keep track of the total number of changes on the page, for all textboxes. I want it do be instance-specific, for each individual textbox.

What is the preferred way to solve this? Don't know if it matters, but I should mention that my real scenario is much more complex, with more state variables than just one as in this example.

Thanks!
/Fredrik

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of JavaScript's prototype nature and extend textboxes on an as-used basis, like so:

```
function HandleOnChangeEvent(e) {

    // `e` contains the DOM element that was clicked
    if( !e.numberOfChanges ) e.numberOfChanges = 0; // dynamically set the property
    e.numberOfChanges++;
    alert( e.numberOfChanges );
}
```

You need to change your `onchange` attribute to this:

```
onchange="HandleOnChangeEvent(this);"
```

Comment: Aha, that's clever - didn't think about that. 

My case is a little more complex, though. Still simplified, consider this example:

I have a composite control, which contains two textboxes. I still want "numberOfChanges" to appear each time the user changes a value in either of the textboxes. 

In other words, the state is unique to the composite control, but shared across the two textboxes. ("this" in your example would refer to one of the textboxes, right?)

How could that be solved? I need to place the numberOfChanges-variable somehere.

Comment: Replace `this` with `document.getElementById("idOfTheFirstTextbox");`